'Catching' webhook event in Azure
To give context of the current situation:
We have an external CRM application which has the option to 'generate' a webhook event whenever a specific event within the web app (web software?) happens and make a POST-request to a URL which is entered by a user (me).
I tested it using webhook.site. I entered the generated URL in the 'webhook' option of the CRM app. I added a trigger (let's say: when a customer gets added) and the CRM app actually triggered the webhook event, which I was able to receive on webhook.site. I was able to see the headers, payload, etc. All the info I wanted to see was there.
I want to replicate this in Azure. I already tried using an Azure Function App and using an Azure Runbook, unfortunately with no success. I can trigger my Runbook with Postman by sending a POST-request to the Webhook URL of my Runbook, but when I enter the Webhook URL in the external CRM app, the Runbook does not trigger.
I am wondering what I am missing. The reason I want to do this in Azure, is that I want to use the information of the CRM app POST request as input for automation purposes (data extraction via API, etc.)
If I provided too little context, please let me know! I will provide additional information if necessary.
Thanks in advance!

you want to use Azure function as webjobs?

Hello there, I do not necessarily want to use Azure Function as webjobs, but if that is the only option to solve my problem, I will gladly use it.

you want to use function url to trigger it from CRM app?

Again, if that is the only option to trigger the Function App then yes, I'd like to use the function URL to trigger it from the CRM app.

Can you share your code? function code or runbook code?

Hello there! I managed to solve my own issue and posted it as an answer to this post! Thanks for your kindness and willingness to help! :)

I managed to solve my own issue in the meantime. The solution to my problem was to add the domain name of the external application to the Allowed Origins list in my Azure Function App.
